# PowerShell - Trying to combine data from 2 CSV files into one based on column value

Tags: powershell, csv

long time listener first time caller.

Normally I am pretty good at finding and digging and getting what I need and then modifying it to suit.  This one seems to be a little trickier than what I have managed to pull off before.  I am self taught in PowerShell mostly out of curiosity to see what I can do.

I am trying to create a report from data from 2 CSVs, and "most" of the data in the 2 CSVs are identical.  There is simply 1 column of data in one of the CSVs that I want to add to the other one.  I live regularly in the world of excel and I can do this with a formula in a matter of seconds [=VLOOKUP(H8,C:C,2,FALSE)] but accomplishing the same goal in PowerShell seems to be eluding me.

As I mentioned, I tend to try and find others who have done similar things and modify it.  The best sounding one I found here ( [Combine data from 2 CSV files into 1 new CSV using Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39964805/combine-data-from-2-csv-files-into-1-new-csv-using-powershell) ) and I am still trying to play with the code on that site.  Sometimes I find something and I try and stick with it too long where there might be another command that I am not familiar with that is better suited to what I should be looking at and might just need a pointer in that direction.

But here is a visual representation of what I am trying to do.
And every email address in File 2, is present in File 1.

[image: File merge]

Answer (score 1):

- Use [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv) to parse both CSV input files into arrays of `[pscustomobject]` instances for OOP processing.
- For file 2, build a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) that maps the `Email` column values to their `License` values.
- Then use a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties) with [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) to append a property to the objects parsed from file 1, using the hashtable to map each `Email` property to the `License` value from file 2; if there is no hashtable entry for a given `Email` property value, `$null` is returned, which in the context of exporting to CSV (with [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv)) amounts to an *empty field* (column value).

```bash
# Import file 2 and create a hashtable that maps each Email
# column value to the License column value.
$ht = @{}
Import-Csv File2 | ForEach-Object { $ht[$_.Email] = $_.License }

# Import file 1 and append a License column that contains
# the license value from file 2 if the Email column value matches.
Import-Csv File1 |
  Select-Object *, @{ Name='License'; Expression={ $ht[$_.Email] } } 
  # | Export-Csv ...  # complete as needed
```

Comment: huh, even last night when I was laying down to bed I was trying to think of ways to use Select-where with ForEach to try and get the license rows to line up in the correct places.  That worked, perfectly well and a far cry easier than I had expected.  For some reason everything in my head had like twice as many lines to get these togeather.

Thank you very much, I will have to add these to my notes for future things I try and do.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @ShaunMcbride.